# How to recognize in powershell that the called gradle build has failed

Tags: powershell, gradle

I am using the following Start-Process call inside a for loop of my script. The aim is to abort the script if the called build has failed. Actually it does not do that. I think I know the reason but have no other way to solve this.

```
    $proc = Start-Process -FilePath 'C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe' -ArgumentList '/c', 
   "$currentProject\dev.bat clean build" -Wait -PassThru

if ($proc.ExitCode -eq 0){
    Write-Host "SUCCESS -->[$currentProject]"
}
else{
    Write-Error "BUILD-ERROR --> $currentProject please fix it first"
    Write-Host "call this manually: $currentProject\dev.bat clean build"
    break
}
```

If somehow the build task failed it returns something like this

```
some error reports and finally this:
BUILD FAILED in 34s
6 actionable tasks: 3 executed, 3 up-to-date
```

In this case my script into the success branch of the if / else because the Start-Process call returned success.

Any idea how I can recognize the "Build Failed" case?
Thanks

Comment: You might have to look for the error string if the exit code isn't set.  You don't need start-process unless it runs in the background and you need to wait.

Comment: I need to wait for each build to finish before starting the next build. How can i access the error string?

Comment: What is in dev.bat?

Comment: It looks like your dev.bat isn’t propagating the exit code from whatever you’re calling inside it. You might need to add some error handling inside that and call something like ```exit  /b %errorlevel%``` in the batch file if your build fails…